# "Attempt to invoke interface method 'voidorg.unimodules...' on null object reference" error message with a React-Native app on an android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

My expo app ran fine on ios, but it would crash without an error message on android, so I converted it to a bare react-native app using expo eject and now I am getting this error on my Android emulator. "Attempt to invoke interface method 'voidorg.unimodules.interfaces.taskManager.TaskServicesInterface.setTaskManager(org.unimodules.interfaces.taskManager.TaskManagerInterface,jaka.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on null object reference" Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Until today, this is an unsolved error.
found the same error in the official issue tracker: https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules/issues/76

In the documentation of expo-task-manager they state that

> It [TaskManager] is not yet available for bare React Native apps. If you're using the bare workflow, React Native's [Headless JS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) might suit your needs.

If you don't really need it, remove the package from your `package.json`.